# How to use data from another component in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a component1 with list of data, this component render ListView with data, if i clicked on ListView item i navigate by *this.props.navigator.push()* to component2 (detail view of ListView item), how can i send data about item from component1 to component2?

Comment: use `navigator` to pass data like this: `this.props.navigator.push({data:data})`, and when you render the component2 you can get it from `route.data`

Comment: ty, it's helped for me

Comment: @AlexanderKushnir can you share the code.

Comment: @Siou can you show me with and example

Comment: @PramodJGeorge
Read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#renderscene) first, in `renderScene` function  
you can get the current `route` , and what the route looks like depends on you. In this example, when the listItem is onPress I will call  `navigator.push({title: 'listDetail', data: itemData})` ,  so in `renderScene` I can get a route which includes `title`(decide what component to render) and the `data`(i want to send to the component).

Comment: @Siou thanks for the answer. so if we send data:{username:'test'} I can access the value via route.data.username

Comment: @PramodJGeorge Yes!  By the way, you can use [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#getcurrentroutes) to check the route list